# How to calculate total time from date column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table where i have some log like this.

```
select table_name,  
    min(to_char(DATO,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')) as start_time, 
    max(to_char(DATO,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')) as end_time
from TMP_AUDIT_LOG t
where FLAG='Y'
and TR_MODE='EXPORT'
group by T.TABLE_NAME
order by 2
```

and output is like below

```
TABLE_NAME  START_TIME          END_TIME
----------  ----------------    ----------------
MAPTEXT     06.11.2020 17:29    06.11.2020 18:12
COMPONENT   06.11.2020 18:12    06.11.2020 19:18
SETTKONT    06.11.2020 19:18    06.11.2020 20:24
ROUTELOG    06.11.2020 20:24    06.11.2020 20:44
CROSSEC     06.11.2020 20:44    06.11.2020 20:49
```

But I want to have one more column which will give me total time like below

```
TABLE_NAME  START_TIME          END_TIME          TOTAL_TIME
----------  ----------------    ----------------  ----------
MAPTEXT     06.11.2020 17:29    06.11.2020 18:12  43m
COMPONENT   06.11.2020 18:12    06.11.2020 19:18  1h 6m
SETTKONT    06.11.2020 19:18    06.11.2020 20:24  1h 6m
ROUTELOG    06.11.2020 20:24    06.11.2020 20:44  24m
CROSSEC     06.11.2020 20:44    06.11.2020 20:49  5m
```

I have tried to minus both time but not getting proper result.

```
select table_name, start_time, end_time, 
(to_date(end_time,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')-to_date(start_time,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')) as total_time from (
select table_name,  
  min(to_char(DATO,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')) as start_time, 
  max(to_char(DATO,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')) as end_time
from TMP_EXPORT_WORKSPACE t
where FLAG='Y'
and TR_MODE='EXPORT'
group by T.TABLE_NAME
order by 2
)
;
```

The output i am getting is below

```
TABLE_NAME  START_TIME          END_TIME          TOTAL_TIME
----------  ----------------    ----------------  ----------
MAPTEXT     06.11.2020 17:29    06.11.2020 18:12  0.0298611111111111111111111111111111111111
COMPONENT   06.11.2020 18:12    06.11.2020 19:18  0.0458333333333333333333333333333333333333
SETTKONT    06.11.2020 19:18    06.11.2020 20:24  0.0458333333333333333333333333333333333333
ROUTELOG    06.11.2020 20:24    06.11.2020 20:44  0.0138888888888888888888888888888888888889
CROSSEC     06.11.2020 20:44    06.11.2020 20:49  0.003472222222222222222222222222222222222222
```

Comment: `min(to_char` - Don't convert to text to make calculations!

Comment: i have tried this too.. 
min(to_date(to_char(DATO,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'),'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')) as start_time
still no luck

Comment: What type is `dato`? `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: it is DATE only

Comment: This is good. `DATE` is Oracle's inappropriate name for a datetime. I don't know why you are trying to make this datetime a string (`TO_CHAR`) or make this datetime a datetime (`TO_DATE`) at all. It is a datetime already. Exactly what you need. (The same would apply for a timestamp of course, which is a datetime, too, only that it allows higher precision and optionally timezones.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't convert the dates to strings. That makes no sense and only leads to unexpected results. The column `dato` is a `DATE` and per table you want the minimum `dato` and the maximum `dato`, so just use `MIN(dato)` and `MAX(dato)`. Then you want the difference. You get the difference by subtracting one from the other:

```
select
  table_name,  
  min(dato) as start_time, 
  max(dato) as end_time,
  max(dato) - min(dato) as total_time
from tmp_audit_log t
where flag = 'Y'
and tr_mode = 'EXPORT'
group by table_name
order by start_time;
```

As `dato` is a `DATE`, you get the difference as a fraction of days. If you want an `INTERVAL` instead, convert from `DATE` to `TIMESTAMP`:

```
max(cast(dato as timestamp)) - min(cast(dato as timestamp)) as total_time
```

Comment: Thanks, cast worked for me. without that time is coming as fraction as per my earlier output.